# An exception occurred while instantiating a Java object. The class must not be an interface or an abstract class. Error: ''

Tags: java, coldfusion, cfc

This error has occurred in my cfc page. Previous developer has made the code, I am very new to Java also. This is happening in the nightly schedule jobs which runs on the production server.

some part of CODE :

```
<cffunction name="createJavaProxy" hint="create a javaproxy, dependent on CF server settings" access="private" returntype="any" output="false">
<cfargument name="class" hint="the java class to create the proxy with" type="any" required="Yes">
<cfscript>
    return createObject("java", "coldfusion.runtime.java.JavaProxy").init(arguments.class);
</cfscript><cffunction>
```

The error line is : "return createObject........"

Comment: You will have to read Java code or post it here.  
Check if the class `JavaProxy` has any `static` methods which may return an instance of the class, if not than you will need to look for  a class that `extends JavaProxy` class.

Comment: Please post the stack trace that is being generated for this error.

Comment: What value are you passing as the `class` argument to `createJavaProxy()`? By the looks of it, it's... an interface or an abstract class. Which it can't be (hence the error).

Comment: Unfortunately CF also uses it as a boilerplate error message when working with java objects, so the cause may be something quite different. As mentioned, a) When using java objects, the true error is usually in the [stack trace](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/ColdFusion/9.0/Developing/WSc3ff6d0ea77859461172e0811cbec22c24-7d24.html), we need to see that trace and b) what is the full `arguments.class` value?

Comment: @GermannArlington - Technically, the above is using reflection behind the scenes, so Harmlezz's suggestion was not totally off the wall ;-)

Comment: @Leigh AFAIR CF compiles it's pages, but I am not sure how it processes `createObject` calls. Are you saying that they were not bright enough to get all required information from the class at compile time and then use Java standard object instantiation [init() is just a constructor call]?

Comment: @GermannArlington - Internal classes may be a different, but for arbitrary classes, yes it uses reflection to locate constructors and methods. Given CF's relative "typelessness", I do not think you can reliably determine which constructors or methods to invoke until runtime. Granted the information is probably cached after that.

Comment: Obviously the above is not actually creating an *instance* of the class, just the proxy, but in general java objects are manipulated via reflection.

Comment: @Leigh Thanks, I never actually looked at it while I was in CF world...

Comment: @GermannArlington  - Oh, you are *that* GArlington. I remember seeing some of your posts in the CF archives :) Yeah, it was kind of a black box in the beginning, but tools like Mark Mandel's JavaLoader opened things up a bit.

Comment: For the love of all that is holy, why would you have this entire function be tag based, but wrap the `return` in `cfscript`? Either use all tags (you could use `cfreturn`) or all script. Don't mix both. And, yes, I know this has nothing to do with the issue, but that there is some ugly looking code.